# Show/Hide Divs by name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have the following JavaScript at the end of the body of my HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var div_to_show=event.target.id;
        var real_div=div_to_show.split('-');
        var display_div=real_div[0];
        var elementPos=$("#"+div_to_show).offset();
        var top_pos=elementPos.top-118.5;           
        $('#board-right div').hide(); 
        $("#" + display_div).css('margin-top',top_pos); 
        $("#" + display_div).show(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the HTML that it is supposed to manipulate:

```
<div id="board-left">
<div id="board-names">
    <a id="marci-link">Marci Weisler</a><br />
    <a id="nicholas-link">Nicholas Rey</a><br />
</div>
</div><!-- #board-left -->

<div id="board-right">
    <div id="marci" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        Marci Weisler is an accomplished...
    </p>
</div>
<div id="nicholas" style="display:none;">
    <p>
        Nicholas Rey is a French-born...
    </p>
</div>      
</div><!-- board-right -->
```

So, the code should get the div name from the clicked link, remove the "-link" portion, and then show the appropriate div.  Currently nothing is happening when I click the link.  As I'm writing this, I am wondering if it is a CSS issue?  Any ideas?

By the way, there is a link in the document to jQuery 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check http://jsfiddle.net/pramodpv/YvYBD/,

you will find that the top pos is negative.. if u correct that as u require it will work

PS: try using jsfiddle while posting your questions so that people can work on your code and give faster answers... Most prb, you will find the answer yourself :D

Comment: Thank you.  Your link to jsfiddle was most helpful, as was your correction to the code.

Comment: also have updated the jsfiddle with the points mentioned by @EricBowden regarding href="#" and event.preventDefault()[i have used return false instead]

Answer (score 2):

Trying your example, I found that I had to add an href='#' attribute to the hyperlinks and then added an event.preventDefault() as the first line in your click handler.

And same as Pramod SyneITY, the top position needs to evaluate as a positive value for the text to be visible.